# Woocommerce shop manager can't see previous media files

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have just created a shop manager role inside my site. I want someone else  to upload my site content like product details and images. But right now this role can't see the old product images in media library. When i open media library, i see empty.

Answer (score 1):

To view all images login back from admin account. Shop Manager is a role you can give someone to manage the shop without making them an admin. They’re granted the capabilities:

- manage_woocommerce
- view_woocommerce_reports

If you wish to modify roles and capabilities, use a third-party plugin such as [Capability Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capsman/) or [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/)

Comment: I removed woocommerce tab for shop manager via functions.php. Because i dont want to let the shop manager to see site orders and other woocommerce settings.